# C reallocing a typedef?

Tags: c, typedef

I need a struct declaration that contains a single string which I can then make an array of(so basically an array of pointers to strings). I know how to make an array of structs which each contain a string:

```
typedef char line_t[MAX_INPUT + 1];

typedef struct {
line_t text;
} lines;

lines *arrayoflines;
arrayoflines = (char *)calloc(MAX_INPUT + 1, sizeof(char));
```

No issue here. However, what if the number of characters in the string that needs to be stored goes past the bounds of `MAX_INPUT`? I feel I'd need to realloc `char line_t[MAX_INPUT + 1]` and that is what I have absolutely no idea how to do.

Edit: Seems like some thought that the number of strings in the array of strings was the issue. I meant reallocating for the length of the string that can be stored in each element in the array of strings.

Comment: why not just prevent the input from exceeding MAX_INPUT

Comment: @Les university assignment question - I don't know the size of the input. It could be anything. My lecturer is a harsh human.

Comment: still, you will know the size of your input when your program reads it.  as for your initial allocation, typically it would be...  arrayoflines = calloc(1,sizeof(lines));

Comment: If you want more lines later, it would be... arrayoflines = realloc(arrayoflines, N * sizeof(lines));  where N is the new number of lines.  Note: the new space will not be initialized, so you may want to use memset() on the new portion of your array.

Comment: @Les the number of lines I know how to reallocate just fine. The size of each line is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a limit for the maximum line defined in your array.  So, I assume any given line will never exceed that (you should check your input if this assumption is wrong).  You can read a shorter line into the line_t (by terminating your string with a NULL), but you will not recover the space in memory.  If you don't have many lines expected, your fixed buffer approach will work, i.e., you don't need to realloc.

However, if you need to be efficient with space, maybe because you will read millions of lines, you should allocate memory for each line.  In other words, you might consider changing line_t to a char* instead of char[MAX_INPUT+1].  They are semantically equal for your programming purposes.  But behind the scene, you are not setting a fixed size.

```
typedef char* line_t;

line_t *arrayoflines;
arrayoflines = calloc(1, sizeof(line_t));
arrayoflines[0] = calloc(MAX_INPUT + 1, sizeof(char));

//if you learn the size after reading into the buffer, and it's smaller,
// realloc the buffer - be sure to include space for NULL and be sure it
// is set to NULL
arrayoflines[0] = realloc(arrayoflines[0], (new_smaller_count+1) * sizeof(char))
arrayoflines[0][new_smaller_count] = NULL;
```

Comment: Why does `new_smaller_count` need to be set to `NULL`?

Comment: @Laefica - you are right, if the initial allocation is calloc'ed it is already null.  I have a habit of explicitly storing the NULL.

Comment: Oh, yep. Sorry I read that wrong. Haven't seen that get used. My tutor/lecturer have always done in this situation `arrayoflines[0][new_smaller_count] = '\0'`

Answer (score 3):

It is better to allocate memory for each line. I.e. instead of array of static arrays `line_t[MAX_INPUT + 1]` define array of `char` pointers: `char ** arrayoflines`.

Comment: By this you mean allocate memory to each element of an array of structs individually?

Comment: @Laefica Not array of structs but array of `char`-s. It is harder to do separate `malloc` but the usage of memory will be optimal. With static arrays you will waste memory for unused chars.

Comment: You have to allocate memory for each element: `arrayoflines[0] = (char *)malloc( line_len + 1)`. Then you can copy line: `strcpy( arrayoflines[0], _your_string_buf_ )`. PS: Don't forget to `free` elements at the end.

Answer (score 0):

if you can not ensure that the all the inputs will be less or equal  MAX_INPUT, you have to convert to dynamic allocation instead.
and by that you have to do this:

```
typedef struct {
    char * text;
} lines;
lines *arrayoflines;
arrayoflines =  calloc(MAX_LINES, sizeof(lines));
```

and for every (n) element allocate THE_DESIRED_INPUT_SIZE for that particular element;

```
arrayoflines[n].text=calloc(THE_DESIRED_INPUT_SIZE, sizeof(char));
```

the (n) is in range of [0,MAX_LINES-1]